# How do I graph the output of an equation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I have a function:

function [ Result ] = Calc_Result(A, B, C, D)

How do I graph the output of this function, for values A=0.00 to A=1.00, in steps of 0.01? Variables B,C,D are constants.

If the function returns NaN at any point on the graph, I need some method handling this (Matlab shouldn't fall over).

Comment: Did you mean "for values A=0.00 to **A** =1.00"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As strictlyrude27 said, if your function can deal with vectorisation, you can just use

```
x=0:0.01:1;
y=Calc_Result(A, B, C, D);
plot(x,y,'.-');
```

If not, you can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) to avoid a loop:

```
x=0:0.01:1;
y=arrayfun(@(A) Calc_Result(A, B, C, D),x);
plot(x,y,'.-');
```

[`plot`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) deals with NaNs gracefully by default (it doesn't plot them and breaks the line it draws at every NaN).

Comment: +1 - I never remember `arrayfun()` and `cellfun()`. Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: @strictly You are welcome :-). I learned using those functions from StackOverflow... so thanks goes to gnovice, Jonas, Amro and the other heros of the Matlab tag ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
fplot(@(A) Calc_Result(A, B, C, D), [0 1]);
```

`fplot` immediately plots `Calc_Result` on the interval [0 1]. `fplot` does not plot `NaN` values. Note that this code doesn't specify that you wanted to plot 100 points between 0 and 1 (i.e., plot at stepsizes of 0.01); `fplot` doesn't care about that.

If you needed that data in addition to plotting it, you could always generate it first, then plot the data afterward. If the function isn't already built to take care of matrix inputs, you could do this:

```
xvals = [];
yvals = [];
for A = 0:0.01:1
    y = Calc_Result(A, B, C, D);
    if ~ isnan(y)
        yvals = [yvals y];
        xvals = [xvals A];
    end
end
plot(xvals, yvals);
```

If it *is* built to deal with matrix inputs (i.e., you have a `.` in the right places to perform element-by-element multiplication and division), you could just do something like

```
A = 0:0.01:1;
y = Calc_Result(A, B, C, D);
```

Without knowing when it returns `NaN` values though, I think your best bet is to go with the for-loop. It might be a little slower than using matrix inputs, but with only 100 values to calculate I don't think it's a big deal.